# Реализация splay-дерева.

Tags: дерево

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с реализацией splay-дерева. На примере такой задачи : *прочитать файл с программой на языке Си и подсчитать количество всех знаков операций* ( "+", "<<" и т. д. ). Записывать все это я пытаюсь в дерево. Для проверки я пытаюсь в конце вывести количество плюсов. Но мне на это выдается куча ошибок...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку:

```
    return z;
    splay (z);
}
```

Это что?

```
struct splay_tree *q = new splay_tree;
```

Это что?

```
// Инициализируем певые три элемента таким образом. Чтобы файл не упустить конец файла.
```

1) Упустили, если длина файла < 3

2) `fgetc()` возвращает `int`, читать в `char` - создавать проблемы, ну да ладно

```
item = (struct splay_tree *)calloc(i, sizeof(struct splay_tree));
```

Чему равно `i` в этой точке? Правильно, `0`...

```
realloc (item, i); // Перевыделяем память на еще один элемент дерева
```

И куда её сохраняем?

```
j = ( (find (root, 43) ) -> count );
```

А если `find()` вернёт `NULL`?

Это только беглый просмотр кода, без включения головы и попыток в нём разобраться...